# C# - Problem reading File memorystream in my MVC project

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, memorystream

As my code is shown below, the uploaded image file is sometimes read empty (`fileContents` is set to 0) or half read. As I have tested I could see that `fileContents` is receiving the proper value when I slowly step-over from `myViewModel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);` to `myViewModel.Image =...` using the debug mode. So I believe there is a problem with the memorystream copy but I don't understand why.

However when I sleep the thread by removing the commented `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` then reading the image is done propely and the `fileContents` get the proper value. Can the problem be caused by the declaration `using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())`? What is the problem caused by and is there a better way to fix this issue rather than sleeping the thread?

```
  if (myViewModel.File != null)
        {
            byte[] fileContents;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                myViewModel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                fileContents = memoryStream.ToArray();
                myViewModel.Image = new MyImage{ FileName = myViewModel.File.FileName, File = myViewModel.File, ContentType = myViewModel.File.ContentType, FileData = fileContents };
            }
        }
```

Comment: of course that would happen when you call an async method without awaiting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not **waiting** for myViewModel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream) to complete.

Either use

```
await myViewModel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
```

or don't use async at all:

```
myViewModel.File.CopyTo(memoryStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling an asynchronous method without awaiting it.

`myViewModel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);`

Can you rewrite your method as `async` and use the word `await`?

Then you can await the CopyToAsync method.

`await myViewModel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);`